# How to boost mplayer (SMPlayer) sound (in Lubuntu)?

Tags: sound, lubuntu, mplayer, smplayer

- I am thinking of the useful feature present in the [MPUI video player](http://mpui.sourceforge.net/) (mplayer for windows) that can enable volume boost to impressive levels (not from the volume slider, but just from the mouse scroll).
  [image]
- In L/ubuntu I use VLC for the same purpose - normally up to 200%.

[image]

- I have found [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/61634/47206) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/180916/47206) related questions that imply overall volume boost and do not specify the desktop environment, which usually means they are Gnome-Unity specific. 
  I think the answers related to using the volume properties in order to boost overall volume above 100% is useful in LXDE/Lubuntu too, as Pulseaudio Volume Control can be used in LXDE.
  [image]

But I would like to know if there's a way to do that with mplayer/smplayer - to get more boost.

**I thought that maybe mplayer would do in Ubuntu/Lubuntu at least what it can do in Windows. But *how*?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open SMPlayer, go to **Options > Preferences**. Under *General*, click the tab *Audio*.

There should be an option `Use software volume control` and next to it the maximum amplification. See this screenshot (my SMPlayer version is 0.8.3):
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a complement to the question but it can stand as a partial answer or workaround.

Pulseaudio Volume Control (not installed by default in Ubuntu, to install go to [pavucontrol [image: Install pavucontrol]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol) ) would display  the audio player/module that is runing and increase that.

So, VLC, already playing at 200%, can get a supplementary boost

[image]

And from what I see the sound is not distorted.

Also while playing SMPlayer.

[image]

This involves directly the mplayer module.

I guess that this solution can be added to the other answer (that i'll set as the permanent to the question "how to boost audio in smplayer").

Comment: Ah, I like this, is `pavucontrol` installed by default on Lubuntu? For Ubuntu it is not...

Comment: @Gerhard Burger: I do not think so but cannot tell for sure. But you can install it can't you?

Comment: Yes, I know. I was just wondering why Ubuntu doesn't have it by default, it is way better!

Comment: @Gerhard Burger: better than what app? what is the default in ubuntu unity? there's also xfce4-mixer that deserves maybe a look, but maybe pavucontrol is indeed the best. i thought in fact that it is default in ubuntu proper

Comment: In Unity you have a built in sound menu, which doesn't have as many mixer controls.

Comment: @GerhardBurger, @cipricus, `dpkg --get-selections` doesn't show `pavucontrol` as installed in Lubuntu 12.10.