# How can i make the Firefox Totem Plugin open VLC instead of Totem when opening an online video in a new window?

Tags: 11.10, firefox, vlc, totem

Until 11.04 the Firefox Totem Plugin offered to open the video in VLC, now it offers to open it in Totem. How can I change it back to vlc?

Note: I do not want to install the VLC plugin nor do I wish to automatically open VLC when watching a, say, .avi video.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Firefox to always ask which application to use when opening such content. If the application you want to use has the needed plugin already installed, it should be listed as one of the options. If not, you can usually "Browse" to the executable file of the app you want to use, usually located at /usr/bin. Here's how to make sure Firefox prompts to ask which application you want to use:

1.) open Firefox and go to Edit > Preferences

2.) select the "Applications" section

3.) find the "AVI video" listing

4.) under the "Action" heading, select "Always ask"[image: "Always ask"]

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what i asked for. I want the Totem Plugin to behave other way. I am perfectly fine with the Totem Plugin handling .avi files in Firefox itself, but i would like to have the option to open the video in VLC in the Totem Plugin (not in Firefox itself)

Comment: I'm not following you, could you explain a little more?

Comment: Do you mean you want to open a video directly in VLC, like via Media > Open Network Stream...

Comment: Well: When opening a .avi video on a website on Firefox, Totem Plugin handles the Video. In its menu on the down right side, it offers to open it with Totem (not the plugin, the actual program Totem Player). It will launch a new Totem window playing the video. Until 11.04, it used to open vlc (at least on my machine). I would like to have this back, because vlc offers more options.  Long story short: I want the Totem Plugin to offer me to open the displayed video in vlc instead of Totem.

Comment: The answer I gave will do this. Can you give me a link that I can try on my box? If you set Firefox to Always ask, then when the Totem Plugin goes active it will prompt, which app? You then select VLC as the app you want. The video will then popup and play in VLC.

Comment: http://www.funny-games.biz/videos/1766-submissive-dog.html lets say this one. problem is: your solution does not work for me insofar as it does not do what you tell me, even when i restart firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a different add-on. Use the [Firefox Openwith addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-with/) and just add vlc  instead of/beside browsers. And it works perfectly.

[image]

More info [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/169410/47206).

Comment: Thank you very much, that sounds good. Unfortunately, my nice little linux desktop pc has died and i cant have ubuntu on my work laptop. but i will try your solution as soon as possible. does it work for divx videos as well?

Comment: haven't tried it that much, but opening the link in vlc should work, as the addon is not flash-specific. you may post for me a link to test here. in fact this addon should work in Firefox on all OS. more here>http://askubuntu.com/a/169630/47206.. look at this too:https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mediaplayerconnectivity/?src=search -

Comment: well, correction: the limits of the addon are mostly related to the website, i think, and less to the type of video. some flash outside youtube and daily motion for example would not open as smoothly.look at the link i posted

Comment: well, thank you very much for the tipp. i will try it as soon as possible (which is, having an ubuntu pc)

Comment: as i said , the addon is not just for ubuntu

Comment: thats right, but i got no problem on windows :)